# conda cammand not found after Anaconda install

Tags: bash, anaconda, conda

I just installed Anaconda as instructed from the homepage.

- Downloaded installer
- checked sum:

  ```
  $ shasum -a 256 ~/Downloads/Anaconda3-2022.10-Linux-x86_64.sh 
  e7ecbccbc197ebd7e1f211c59df2e37bc6959d081f2235d387e08c9026666acd  /home/akil/Downloads/Anaconda3-2022.10-Linux-x86_64.sh
  ```
- install Anaconda

  ```
  bash ~/Downloads/Anaconda3-2022.10-Linux-x86_64.sh
  ```
- Accepted all default settings, until final welcome message.

```
...
Thank you for installing Anaconda3!

===========================================================================

Working with Python and Jupyter is a breeze in DataSpell. It is an IDE
designed for exploratory data analysis and ML. Get better data insights
with DataSpell.

DataSpell for Anaconda is available at: https://www.anaconda.com/dataspell
```

How ever, I cannot use `conda` command.

```
$ conda init
conda: command not found
```

Ubuntu version:

```
$ lsb_release -a
No LSB modules are available.
Distributor ID: Ubuntu
Description:    Ubuntu 22.04.1 LTS
Release:    22.04
Codename:   jammy
```

**EDIT**

output of `./conda init bash` in `~/anaconda3`:

```
$  cd ~/anaconda3/bin/
$ ./conda init bash

~/anaconda3/bin$ ./conda init bash
no change     /home/akil/anaconda3/condabin/conda
no change     /home/akil/anaconda3/bin/conda
no change     /home/akil/anaconda3/bin/conda-env
no change     /home/akil/anaconda3/bin/activate
no change     /home/akil/anaconda3/bin/deactivate
no change     /home/akil/anaconda3/etc/profile.d/conda.sh
no change     /home/akil/anaconda3/etc/fish/conf.d/conda.fish
no change     /home/akil/anaconda3/shell/condabin/Conda.psm1
no change     /home/akil/anaconda3/shell/condabin/conda-hook.ps1
no change     /home/akil/anaconda3/lib/python3.9/site-packages/xontrib/conda.xsh
no change     /home/akil/anaconda3/etc/profile.d/conda.csh
no change     /home/akil/.bashrc
No action taken.
```

Comment: Which version of Ubuntu are you using?

Comment: Try `./anaconda3/bin/conda init bash`, and then logout/login

Comment: @ArchismanPanigrahi `22.04`  as shown in question edit.

Answer (score 0):

I faced the same issue yesterday, while installing conda in a cluster.

You have to initialize Conda to use bash.
Opena  terminal and run

```
cd anaconda3/bin/
./conda init bash
```

Now logout/login or reboot for the new configurations to load.

Comment: not available even after system reboot.

Comment: changed  to the dir and issued the command, `No action taken`  as in the edit. This is after system reboot.